# Environ("USERNAME") with multiple users logged in. VBA

Tags: vba, environment

I'm in search of a methode to look up a list of all connected users. I've found the Environ("USERNAME") function, but this only shows the username of myself, even though that there currently is 7 users logged on(Checked in the "Users" tab in "Task Manager").

Do anyone know how to get a full list of all users using VBA?

Thanks in advance.
T.

Comment: You might have to play a little with WMI API.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out who's logged into a particular Excel Workbook, Word Document or similar?

Comment: @Jiminy Cricket No, I'm trying to figure out who's logged into the same server for a SCADA system. Not if you have the actual program open, just if you are logged on.

[Picture of userlist](http://imgur.com/a/k8Xaq)